# Let $z_n=(x_n,y_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R^2$. Show that $\lim z_n=z=(x,y)$ if, and only if, $\lim x_n=x$ and $\lim y_n=y$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Pretty much what it says on the tin. I got a very initial idea for the reverse, but got stuck. Any help? No clue about the forward implication.

**Reverse:**

Since we know that $\lim x_n=x$ we know that there exists $N_x$ such that when $n>N_x$, then $d(x_n,x)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Likewise, since we know that $\lim x_n=y$ we know that there exists $N_y$ such that when $n>N_y$, then $d(y_n,y)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Set $N=max\{N_x,N_y\}$.

Then when $n>N$, by the Triangle Inequality:

$d(x_n,y_n)<d(x_n,x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y_n)$

Is this anything?

Comment: Can you relate the metric on $\Bbb R^2$ to the one on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: No indication, so I'm assuming we're using the usual metrics.

Comment: Can you relate these with inequalities?

Comment: There is no $d(x,y)$. What you want on your last line is to show that $d(z_n,z)<\varepsilon$. To do this, as @HennoBrandsma mentioned, you will need to figure out what $d(z_n,z)$ is less than, in relation to $d(x_n,x)$ and $d(y_n,y)$.

Comment: So I got the inequalities from the answer below, no problem. Makes sense. Still can't go from that to $d(z_n,z)<ε$...

Answer (score 1):

$$d(z,z_{n}) = \sqrt{d(x,x_{n})^{2} + d(y,y_{n})^{2}} $$

So we get the inequalities :

$$d(x,x_{n})\leq d(z,z_{n})$$

$$d(y,y_{n})\leq d(z,z_{n})$$

So if $d(z,z_{n})\to 0$ then $d(y,y_{n}) \to 0$ and $d(x,x_{n}) \to 0$.

Also taking the max under the radical:

$$d(z,z_{n}) \leq \sqrt{2} max(d(x,x_{n}),d(y,y_{n})) $$

So if $d(y,y_{n}) \to 0$ and $d(x,x_{n}) \to 0$ then $max(d(x,x_{n}),d(y,y_{n})) \to 0$, so $d(z,z_{n})\to 0$.

Comment: You need the lemma $z_{n} \to z$ iff $d(z_{n},z) \to 0$. Which I assume you have.

Comment: Use "\to" to get $\to$.

Comment: @ndhanson Thanks

Comment: @open problem I don't... Not seen in class, can't use it.

Comment: Luckily in this case you can replace $d(x,x_{n})$ with $|x-x_{n}|$ which will take care of most of the issues since you have probably seen that. I just wanted to put it in the general cartesian format. For $z$ you may want to prove a lemma first.